# Javascript this.u undefined when using in function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I am programming a discord bot in node.js, I am working on a feature where the bot executes a function every hour beginning at startup.

In this example I replaced setInterval with setTimeout for the sake of testing.

```
class Controller {

    constructor() {
            this.u = new u.Util();
            this.prefix = ".";
    }

    updateRanks(guilds){

            guilds.forEach(g => {

                this.u.updateRanksAuto(g);

                setTimeout(function(){
                    this.u.updateRanksAuto(g);
                }, 6000 );
            });
    }
}
```

The first time I call `this.u.updateRanksAuto(g)` it works perfectly, but obviously this only executes once.

When I try it inside the function it tells me `this.u` is undefined.

I feel like this in an obvious mistake but I can't figure it out.

Comment: You aren't using an arrow function for `setTimeout`, and have no explicit `.bind` to set `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function()` creates new context, so `this` refers to this function. 
You can use arrow instead:

```
setTimeout(() => 
{
    this.u.updateRanksAuto(g);
}, 6000 );
```

or store `this` in some variable or use `.bind(this)`

Comment: Thanks, this is so obvious in hindsight. Sorry for being a noob!

Comment: `this` never refers to the function

Comment: [In most cases, the value of this is determined by how a function is called](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution and let me know if it works

```
class Controller {

    constructor() {
            this.u = new u.Util();
            this.prefix = ".";
    }

    updateRanks(guilds){
            let that = this;
            guilds.forEach(g => {

                that.u.updateRanksAuto(g);

                setTimeout(function(){
                    that.u.updateRanksAuto(g);
                }, 6000 );
            });
    }
}
```